# the email and password don't get passed to firebase through the states

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I get the error:email is badly formatted whenever I use the login form and the password doesn't get to firebase too

here's the error screenshot:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0GbM.jpg)

here's the code for the login form:

```
    class LoginView extends React.Component {
  


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email   : '',
      password: '',
      name:'',
      phone:'',
      fontsLoaded:false,
      isLoading: false,
    }
  }
  async componentDidMount(){
    await Font.loadAsync({
      'comfortaa':require('./assets/fonts/Comfortaa/static/Comfortaa-Bold.ttf'),
    });
    this.setState({fontsLoaded:true})
  }
  updateInputVal = (val, prop) => {
    const state = this.state;
    state[prop] = val;
    this.setState(state);
  }

  registerUser = () => {
    if(this.state.email === '' && this.state.password === '') {
      Alert.alert('Enter details to signup!')
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: true,
      })
      console.log(this.state.email);
      firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
      .then((res) => {
        res.user.updateProfile({
          name: this.state.name
        })
        console.log('User registered successfully!')
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          name: '',
          email: '', 
          password: ''
        })
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message });
        console.log(`Exception in registerUser:${error.message}`);
      })
    }
  }
```

any idea to fix that error and the password error?

Comment: What is the output of  `console.log(this.state.email);`?

Comment: nothing, that's the problem

Comment: when i input email and password,nothing gets passed to firebase

Comment: Flow wise, you'll want to use an `||` in that first statement: `if(this.state.email === '' || this.state.password === '') {`

Comment: why? what does it change?

Comment: Right now if either the password **or** the email is empty, you still send them to Firebase. So if you did enter a password, but no email address, that would go into `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and raise an error. I recommend that you try it, and step through the code in a debugger to see the difference.